# Deploying react app on on Netlify is success and published, but Page Not Found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, web-deployment, netlify

React app with Webpack, babel deployed over netlify showing Page Not Found though the downloaded build is working fine in local.

I've deployed using netlify drop pane by drag-n-drop react app folder. Not with github.

Netlify community topic link for the same -

https://community.netlify.com/t/page-not-found-error-downloaded-build-working-in-local-but-not-on-netlify-site/20094

Here't the site - https://gracious-roentgen-c5c8be.netlify.app/

**Build Status -**
Published deploy
[Production](https://5f28ed3bdc0ccbcb3032c5fc--gracious-roentgen-c5c8be.netlify.app/). Today at 10:38 AM  Download ready

**Deploy log -**
10:38:22 AM: Starting post processing
10:38:22 AM: Post processing - HTML
10:38:23 AM: Post processing - redirect rules
10:38:23 AM: Post processing - header rules
10:38:23 AM: Post processing done
10:38:23 AM: Site is live

**Here's my webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js', '@babel/polyfill'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/images/',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            // {
            //     loader: 'babel-loader',
            //     options: {
            //         presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/env', '@babel/preset-env'],
            //     },
            // },
        ],
        // loaders: [{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel' }],
    },
    devServer: {
        host: '192.168.1.10', //your ip address,
        // host: '0.0.0.0', //your ip address,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: '././src',
        port: 8080,
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('./dist/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        // contentBase: './dist',
        contentBase: './build',
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "dljalpha",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot --host 0.0.0.0",
        "test": "jest",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "webpack": "^4.42.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "husky": "^4.2.5",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.13.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
        "react-intl": "^4.6.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-share": "^4.2.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
        "recompose": "^0.30.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5"
    }
}
```

Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Netlify drop will not build your app for you. You need to drop the `dist` folder that appear when running `npm run build`.

I advice you to use the git workflow with netlify, if you do netlify will build your app and it will be easier for you to update your website. For this you need to push your code to a github repository and create an app from git in netlify.